# Can I filter email using regular expressions in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, regex

I want to block emails in Outlook if the body of the email contains one or more matches for the regular expression `orko\s+from\s+advids` (evaluated case-insensitively). Can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Outlook Search use Regular Expressions (or wild cards)?](https://superuser.com/questions/236784/can-outlook-search-use-regular-expressions-or-wild-cards)

Comment: Not as far as I know, because that question is about searching one's emails, not filtering them.

Comment: You can do most of what you want with Outlook Rules.  Create the conditions in the Advanced Tab and send the email to where you want.

Comment: Thank you John. Will you add that as an answer?

Comment: I added an answer with a Screen Shot that I hopes assists you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to block emails in Outlook if the body of the email contains
> one or more matches for [a]regular expression .... Can this be done?

You can do most of what you want with Outlook Rules.

Create the conditions in the Advanced Tab and send the email to where you want in the Main Rules Tab.

[image: Outlook Rule]

Comment: Good sharing! This is a very good method to use rule to move the emails which meet the conditions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether you can use a regular expression to filter.

Comment: Rules provide a very decent method to block emails .